# Archimedean property concept

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know what the "big deal" about the Archimedean property is. Abbott states it is an important fact about how $\Bbb Q$ fits inside $\Bbb R.$

First, I want to know if the following statements are true:

The Archimedean property states that $\Bbb N$ isn't bounded above--some natural number can be found such that it is greater than some specified real number.

The Archimedean property also states that there is some rational $\frac1n, n \in\Bbb N$ such that it is less than some specified real number.

Secondly, what do the above statements imply about the connection between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R?$ Does it imply that $\Bbb R$ fills the gaps of $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N;$ is it the proof for $\Bbb R$ completing $\Bbb Q?$

Lastly, what insights have you obtained from the Archimedean property?

I am sorry if some of my questions are unclear.

Comment: @GitGud: I don't think the additional tags were needed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was doubtful about topology, not about set theory, though. But you're the expert.

Comment: It is quite important, for it means that (in the reals) there are no "infinitesimals" of the type that were used in the early years of calculus.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I changed my mind, I realise now this has little to do with the construction of the real numbers and concur with your decision.

Comment: @GitGud: You're right. Now, anyway. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila ^_^

Comment: can you question have a proper title? What are you asking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has been pointed out above that your two versions of the Archimedean property should be equivalent--$\Bbb N$ has no upper bound if and only if $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ has no positive lower bound. Your presentations of these two versions were misleading, however (and still are). More precisely:

- Given ***any*** real number $x$, there is a natural number $n$ greater than $x$. This natural number $n$ will of course depend on which $x$ we're looking at in the first place, but we will *always* be able to find *some* (infinitely-many, in fact) natural number greater than $x$, regardless of the $x$ we started with.
- Given ***any*** positive real number $y$, there is a natural number $n$ such that $\frac1n$ is less than $y$. Again, the natural number $n$ will depend on which $y$ we're looking at.

It's a good exercise to show that these are equivalent statements.

---

Now, let me try to explain what Abbott meant by "how $\Bbb Q$ fits inside $\Bbb R$." Specifically, I will show that the following are equivalent:

1. The Archimedean property holds.
2. Given any $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b,$ there is some $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $a<r<b$. (More briefly, $\Bbb Q$ is *dense in* $\Bbb R$.)
3. Given any $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b,$ there is some $p\in\Bbb Z$ and some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $a<\frac{p}{2^n}<b$.

It is clear that 3 $\implies$ 2. To see that 2 $\implies$ 1, take any $x>0,$ and find $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $0<r<x$. We know that $r=\frac mn$ for some positive integers $m,n,$ so $\frac1n\le\frac mn=r<x,$ and so the Archimedean property holds.

To see that 1 $\implies$ 3, we proceed by contrapositive, so suppose that there exist $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ such that for all $p\in\Bbb Z$ and all $n\in\Bbb N,$ we have $\frac{p}{2^n}\le a$ or $\frac{p}{2^n}\ge b$. For each $n\in\Bbb N,$ let $p_n$ the greatest integer $p$ such that $\frac{p}{2^n}\le a.$ (By the Well-ordering property of $\Bbb N,$ such a $p_n$ exists.) From this, it follows by hypothesis that $$\frac{p_n}{2^n}\le a<b\le\frac{p_n+1}{2^n}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. But then $$0<b-a\le\frac{p_n+1}{2^n}-\frac{p_n}{2^n}=\frac1{2^n}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N.$ Since $n<2^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ then it follows that $0<b-a<\frac1n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ and so the Archimedean property fails. Thus, by contrapositive, 1 $\implies$ 3.

Answer (score 7):

In a group with a linear order, if $a$ and $b$ are two positive elements, $a$ is said to be **infinitesimal** with respect to $b$, if no positive integer multiple of $a$ is greater than $b$. Then the linear order is called **Archimedean** if there are no infinitesimal elements. The first two statements you mentioned are easy consequences of $\mathbb{R}$ being Archimedean as a linear order:

If $r$ is any positive real number, since $1$ is not infinitesimal with respect to $r$ by the Archimedean property, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $n.1=n> r$. This shows $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

The second statement is also true for positive real numbers: Suppose we're given a positive real number $r$. Then by the previous property, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $1/r < n$. Therefore $1/n<r$.

---

But to make sense of the rest of your question, we have to use the notion of Archimedean normed fields. If $F$ is a field with an absolute value $|\cdot|$, then $F$ is called **Archimedean** if, given any element $x\in F$, some positive integer multiple of $x$ has absolute value greater than 1: $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}, \ |nx|>1$.

This definition of Archimedean implies the earlier version. Indeed, suppose the normed Archimedean field $F$ is also a linear order, with $|x|=x$ for positive elements. Let $a,b\in \mathbb{F}$ be positive. Then letting $x=a/b$, there must exist an $n$ such that $|nx|>1$. Then by the triangle inequality $|x|+|x|+\cdots +|x| \text{ (n times)} \geq |nx| > 1$. Therefore $1<n|x|=n|a/b|=na/b$, since $a/b$ is positive. Then we have $na>b$, so $a$ is not infinitesimal with respect to $b$. This shows $F$ is Archimedean in the previous sense, so somewhat more indirectly, $\mathbb{R}$ being Archimedean as a normed field also implies the statements you gave.

This property alone does not prove the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, the same properties hold for $\mathbb{Q}$ in place of $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete. Completeness is altogether another property of $\mathbb{R}$, which would take too long to explain here from scratch. The main point is that $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ *with respect to* the ordinary absolute value. It turns out that there are other absolute value functions one can define on $\mathbb{Q}$, and if we repeat the same procedure that we use to make $\mathbb{R}$ out of $\mathbb{Q}$ ,using these absolute values in place of the usual one, we get new completions of $\mathbb{Q}$, the so called $p$-adic fields, which are *not* Archimedean.

Let's firmly fix a prime number $p$. Given a rational number $x$, we can factor $x$ into primes (with negative exponents possibly). If $r$ is the exponent of $p$ that occurs in the factorization of $x$, we define the $p$-adic absolute value of $x$ to be $|x|_p=p^{-r}$. It turns out that this function has the same basic properties as ordinary absolute value. In fact in place of the triangle inequality, something even stronger holds:

$$|x+y|_p \leq \max\{|x|_p,|y|_p\}.$$

This is the so called ultra-metric inequality, and ultimately what makes this absolute value non-Archimedean.

The $p$-adic absolute value may look strange at first, but just like the ordinary absolute value, it measures something about numbers. Whereas the ordinary absolute value $|x|$ quantifies the overall size of a rational number $x$, the $p$-adic absolute value $|x|_p$ measures how far $x$ is divisible by $p$. The higher the power of $p$ that $x$ is divisible by, the closer $x$ is to zero in the $p$-adic absolute value. So for example $250=2\times 5^3$ is much closer to $0$ in $5$-adic absolute value than $2$ is: $|250|_5 = 1/125,\ \ |2|_5 = 1$.

If we form the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to this new absolute value, similar to how we form $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ (taking equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences), we get a new way to "fill the gaps" of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is called the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers.

Unlike $\mathbb{R}$, the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not Archimedean. This is a consequence of the ultra-metric inequality. To see this, suppose $x\in \mathbb{Q}_p$ is any $p$-adic number such that $|x|_p \leq 1$, then we have:

$$|2x|_p =|x+x|_p \leq \max\{|x|_p,|x|_p\}=|x|_p \leq 1.$$

Using $|2x|_p\leq 1$ and $|x|_p\leq 1,$

$$|3x|_p=|2x+x|_p \leq \max\{|x|_p,|2x|_p\} \leq 1,$$

and similarly $|4x|_p=|3x+x|_p\leq \max\{|3x|_p,|x|_p\} \leq 1$, and so by induction $|nx|_p\leq 1$ for all $n$. Thus $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is **non-Archimedean**.

We can also see that in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are bounded above: for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $|n|_p \leq 1$, since the exponent $r$ of $p$ appearing in the prime factorization of $n$ is non-negative: $|n|_p = 5^{-r} \leq 5^0 =1$.

This also shows that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $|1/n|_p \geq 1$, so we can *not* find $1/n$ that are very small in $p$-adic absolute value. So both of the facts that you mentioned in your question are false for $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Now there is a surprising theorem of Ostrowski which says there are no other completions of $\mathbb{Q}$! Any other absolute values that you may define on $\mathbb{Q}$ will be equivalent either to the ordinary absolute value, or to one of the $p$-adics, and after carrying out the completion process, you will get either $\mathbb{R}$, or one of the $p$-adic fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$. This is the sense in which $\mathbb{R}$ is *the* Archimedean completion of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Finally, let me say that although the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is at first a very strange place to play in, it's used by number theorists all the time. Arithmetic in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is sometimes interpreted as doing congruence arithmetic modulo all powers of p at the same time.

Hopefully, the notion of $\mathbb{R}$ being Archimedean is clearer once we are aware of the existence of these non-Archimedean completions. The $p$-adic numbers have many more strangely beautiful properties than can't be mentioned all in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Your statements, strictly interpreted,
are not true.
You need to change the order of quantifiers.

You say
"The Archimedean property states that $\Bbb{N}$ isn't bounded above--some natural number can be found such that it is greater than any real number."
There is *no* natural number "such that
it is greater than any real number."
Rather,
for any positive real number $x$,
there is a natural number $n$ 
such that $n > x$.

Similarly,
you say
"The Archimedean property also states that there is some rational $1/n,n∈ℕ$ such that it is less than any real number."
Rather,
for any positive real number $x$,
there is a positive integer $n$
such that
$1/n < x$.

Be careful out there.

Comment: However, I am confused. If there can be any 1/n found less than some specified real, wouldn't the statement be true anyway for all? Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @MathApprentice: The way you originally put it, you actually *contradicted* the Archimedean property! Suppose there is some natural number $n$ greater than any real number. Now, all natural numbers are real, so $n$ is a real number greater than all real numbers, and so greater than all natural numbers, meaning it is an upper bound of $\Bbb N$ (and is also greater than itself). Now, I suspect that you meant that for any real number $x$ we can find a larger natural number (which is true), but your phrasing suggested otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Both statements you mention are true, and are two different ways of expressing the Archimedean property. For instance, if we have that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}$ with $M$ positive, then $$ n >M \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{M}$$

Regarding your second question, the Archimedean property is not the proof that $\mathbb{R}$ completes $\mathbb{Q}$. That fact is usually proved (though the two ideas are equivalent) from  the least-upper-bound axiom of $\mathbb{R}$. The Archimedean property of $\mathbb{N}$ is a consequence of the least-upper-bound axiom of the real numbers.

Comment: Is there any more significance to the Archimedan Property?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for;  there are plenty of other conclusions you can derive from the Archimedean property, but these seem to be the most general. I would add that the property shows how dangerous it can be to rely on infinitesimals as a basis for calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at some concrete consequences for ordinary calculus. Consider the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$$
I bet you want that equation to be true, right? Well, it requires the Archimedean property! Otherwise, the sequence doesn't converge.* That would be really inconvenient. Similarly, definitions like
$$\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
rely on the Archimedean property, since that sum doesn't converge otherwise.*

**Statements about non-convergence refer to the order topology of a non-Archimedean ordered field. I make no claims about non-ordered fields, such as the $p$-adic numbers.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if Archimedean helps in deriving R from Q. Then you are wrong because Q itself has Archimedean but is not ordered field with least upper bound property. 
I also mention a fact which will help you clearing idea about it(if thsi is question):
An ordered field satisfy Least upper bound property iff it satisfy Archimedean and cauchy completeness property. And R is only ordered field with least upper bound property. This is what we take as definition of R